# Force a negative square root to be interpreted as an I

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have expressions like 
$$\sqrt{-\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$ 
how can I force mathematica to systematically rewrite this as

$$i(1+x^2)^{1/4} \quad ? $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This transformation is not valid for arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{C}$.  You can for example test that it is not valid for `x -> 1+I`.

`PowerExpand` is one way to force the transformation.  From the documentation:

> `PowerExpand` converts `(a b)^c` to `a^c b^c`, whatever the form of `c` is.

with the caveat that

> The transformations made by `PowerExpand` are correct in general only if `c` is an integer or `a` and `b` are positive real numbers.

The following will give a generally valid transformation:

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[-Sqrt[1 + x^2]], Assumptions -> True]

(*  I E^(I π Floor[-(Arg[1 + x^2]/(4 π))]) (1 + x^2)^(1/4)  *)
```

To assume that `x` is real, you can use any of

```
a = Sqrt[-Sqrt[1 + x^2]]

Refine[a, x ∈ Reals]
(* I (1 + x^2)^(1/4) *)

Simplify[a, x ∈ Reals]
(* I (1 + x^2)^(1/4) *)

ComplexExpand[a]
(* I (1 + x^2)^(1/4) *)
```

You might find these options safer as unlike `PowerExpand` they use *simpler* and explicit assumptions.

Comment: Or use `PowerExpand[Sqrt[-Sqrt[1 + x^2]], Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]` which will do the transformation only if valid (which it is). This way you are not relying on `Refine` et al, which may have goals different from `PowerExpand` (and thus not do the desired transformation).

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution to a simple problem

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[-Sqrt[1 + x^2]]]
```

yields 
$$i \sqrt[4]{x^2+1} .$$